# RavenDB how to flush?

Tags: c#, persistence, ravendb, flush

I am using RavenDb embedded. As a part of my intergration tests I want to check objects are persisted. When I SaveChanges on an object, then retrieve it, it cannot be found unless I dispose my connection.

This does not work for me, as no files are returned

```
 using (var session = _dataDocumentStore.Instance.OpenSession())
 {
         session.Store(file);
         session.SaveChanges();
 }
```

....

```
using (var session = _dataDocumentStore.Instance.OpenSession() )
{
          return session.Query<File>().ToList();
}
```

I created a Flush method which disposes and recreates a EmbeddableDocumentStore which works, but as this is somthing that feels fundamental I may be going about things the wrong way:

```
  public static IDocumentStore Initialize()
        {
            instance = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
            {
                DataDirectory = "App_Data/Database",
                UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true,


            };

            instance.Initialize();
            return instance;
        }

        public void Flush()
        {
            instance.Dispose();
            Initialize();

        }
```

How do you persist in RavenDB and then check it has been persisted? Any advice on this would be great

Comment: is there a reason you are calling instance.Initialize(); you are alreading creating a new instance when you get into the IDocumentStore Initialize() Method

Comment: What does the database itself show? Check Raven Studio to make sure your save worked. Is your document there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically, the `EmbeddableDocumentStore` takes longer to save and *Index* that new data, than saving and querying.

So when your tests say:-

1. Store and SaveChanges.
2. Load.
3. Did this load?

*The load completes much quicker than the indexing has had time to finish.*

So, Like Daniel Lang said, you need to wait for stale results.

But, you'll have to do that for *every* query you wish to check, in your code. So, let's cheat (legally) :)

Here is how you can tell your document store to ALWAYS wait for stale results, if something queries the store:

```
// Initialise the Store.
var documentStore = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
                    {
                        RunInMemory = true
                    };
documentStore.Initialize();

// Force query's to wait for index's to catch up. Unit Testing only :P
documentStore.RegisterListener(new NoStaleQueriesListener());

....


#region Nested type: NoStaleQueriesListener

public class NoStaleQueriesListener : IDocumentQueryListener
{
    #region Implementation of IDocumentQueryListener

    public void BeforeQueryExecuted(IDocumentQueryCustomization queryCustomization)
    {
        queryCustomization.WaitForNonStaleResults();
    }

    #endregion
}

#endregion
```

Now to see this in action, check out [RavenOverflow](https://github.com/PureKrome/RavenOverflow) @ Github. And the Tests project in that solution has all the love you might want.

Comment: ++. For version 3: `documentStore.Listeners.RegisterListener`

Answer (score 12):

The reason is, that ravens index is too stale to return something here. You need to do this:

```
session.Query<File>()
    .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
    .ToList();
```

For further reading, go here: http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/stale-indexes